# Empty file part while making multipart post calling using reqwest in rust

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I'm using reqwest to make a async post call with multipart/form-data to upload a file. Even when the byte array is populated, the part is created empty. This might be something basic, but I don't understand why this is happening. Below is the code that I'm using:

```
    pub async fn save_image(&self, image_type: String, image_path: String, bytes: &mut Vec<u8>) {
    let url = format!(
        "{}/object/{}/{}",
        self.config.secrets.base_url, image_type, image_path
    );
    let client = reqwest::Client::new();
    let part = Part::bytes(bytes.to_vec()).file_name("file");
    let file = reqwest::multipart::Form::new().part("file", part);
    let request = client
        .post(url)
        .header("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data")
        .bearer_auth(&self.config.secrets.api_key)
        .multipart(file);
    let response = request.send().await.unwrap();
}
```

I'm on Rust: 1.75.0
and reqwest: 0.11.23 and tokio: 1.35.1

Update:
Supabase api also supports passing the file in the body and setting content-type as the file's mimeType. But this way I had to completely abandon multipart and didn't actually solve the above issue.

[Code (multipart)](https://github.com/JICA98/DailyAL/blob/164dfe6d3e5753d30c33ce4a769eda12444b2295/dal-rust-api/src/file_storage_service.rs#L47)
[Code (body)](https://github.com/JICA98/DailyAL/blob/b1ac0258aa9988eba898a530638a3fc98b9f8f8a/dal-rust-api/src/file_storage_service.rs#L44)

Comment: the code works for me; send a request to `nc -l 8080` and check the output or past it here.

Comment: yes, this is the output: https://gist.github.com/JICA98/e3a88434c29a7f1ab779c22a359a4ea7

Comment: the bytes are there, maybe the server side expects a different format?

Comment: this is the postman request: https://shorturl.at/uUZ38 and this works, am I missing something in code when compared to this request